# WordPress: Create A Widget to Accompany Plugin

Tags: php, plugins

So I have a plugin that I've created for the admin are when creating post... and I'd like to supply a widget along with it.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to initialize my widget. I'm initializing my plugin like so:

```
function call_menu_per_page_class() 
{
    return new MenuPerPage();
}
if ( is_admin() )
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'call_my_class' );
```

Obviously, the widget does NOT require someone to be an admin to view it... it will be viewed in a sidebar within my Theme.

Is there a specific action/filter and hook that I should use to execute my widget class?

Remember, this is being packed with my plugin... so it can't be called from `functions.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Codex [`register_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget) should be hooked to `widgets_init`.

Hook into `init` then and at that point hook further different methods to appropriate hooks later.